# How to add Multiple AND conditions in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, select

I want to add Multiple AND conditions in SQL query as Follows...

```
SELECT CONSUMER_NUMBER
FROM CONSUMER_INFO
WHERE YEAR=2014
  AND CONT='USA'
  AND ROWNUM=1;
```

But it does not work...How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your query is fine syntactically. I think your query is not matching your table structure. Can you provide the table definition for CONSUMER_NUMBER?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? And also are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: what exact error do you get? Are you sure YEAR is stored in the number format?

Comment: YEAR is a Oracle reserved keywords, avoid that! I expected you are using Oracle with ROWNUM.

Comment: Give us some testdata and some exprected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume YEAR is an Integer number, best practice would be to have a column type as data, and get the year using the YEAR function in SQL.

```
SELECT CONSUMER_NUMBER
FROM CONSUMER_INFO
WHERE YEAR(Data) =2014
  AND CONT = 'USA'
  AND ROWNUM = 1 ;
```

Something like this, but anyway I don't think this is the problem with your query, can you prinscreen the error?

PS : Also if your YEAR column is varchar or anything like that don't forget  you have to use `''` ;

Answer (score 0):

This and conditions are right. Do you have column ROWNUM on your table. And what is datatype of YEAR column. You can show me your query errors?